# Generating string primary keys with sequence in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I need improvement on solution to the following problem:

> Generating random string keys in SQA is relatively simple, something
>   like:
>
> ```
> request_id = Column(String, default=lambda: uuid.uuid4().hex, primary_key=True)
> ```
>
> However, I need to to get `request_id` have format like
>   `DIVISION_ABC_REQUEST_223` (this is because PK is also supposed to be
>   good for human consumption -- that key will be sent around in emails,
>   copied/pasted, etc, but it also should be usable for regular SQA/SQL
>   queries as a typical PK), with integer suffixes ideally following a
>   normal (ordinal) sequence.
>
> (the backend DB is Postgres)

I found a solution, if a bit wasteful:

```
class WorkPackage(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'work_package'
    int_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    wp_prefix = Column(Unicode, default=u'DIVISION_ABC_REQUEST_', primary_key=True)
    data = Column(Unicode)

    @hybrid_property
    def wp_id(self):
        return self.wp_prefix + str(self.int_id)

    @wp_id.expression
    def wp_id(cls):
        return cls.wp_prefix.concat(cls.int_id)
```

`wp_id.expression` uses `concat` (a `ColumnOperator` that produces SQL concatenation operator `||`).

It works in the sense of automatic PK creation in desired order and for querying by the `wp_id` attribute.

However, the silly aspect is that obviously there's a single column filled with the same prefix over and over.

The obvious problem here is that `wp_prefix` is a column for a single reason: so that I could use its `concat` method.

I would like to change it in such way that the `wp_prefix` column is unnecessary (e.g. it could be SQL concatenation of a string and `int_id` column).

I do not know how to construct SQLAlchemy Core expression that would achieve this without using column method.

Answer (score 1):

`literal_column("'DIVISION_ABC_REQUEST'").concat...` (note the double quotes, since you want an SQL string expression).

[`literal_column()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.literal_column) essentially means "I hand you this string which is a valid SQL expression and can be used in any column expression-ish context".